# Asyncio with threading no exception throwing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, exception, python-asyncio

I have following code which will use asyncio and thread together. And the code works fine. But the problem is the code not throw exception some error happens.

```
import os
import time
from threading import Thread
import queue


import asyncio

def start_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
    
async def startProcess(name):
    try:
        #dfdf
        print(' Started-----------> ',name)
        
        while True:
            print("Sleeping...",name)
            time.sleep(5)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('Caught exception in worker thread')
        raise e

async def main_app():

    loop1 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    process1_Tread = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(loop1,))
    process1_Tread.start()   
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(startProcess("Thread1"), loop1)
    
     
    while True:
         print("Sleeping main thread...")
         time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main_app())

    finally:
             
        print("Exit...")
```

For example if I add the line

```
     try:
        dfdf # to create exception
        print(' Started-----------> ',name)
```

The thread not works but no error message shows. How can I enable if some error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by referring the answer here

[Asyncio exception handler: not getting called until event loop thread stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413359/asyncio-exception-handler-not-getting-called-until-event-loop-thread-stopped)

Here is the full code

```
import os
import time
from threading import Thread
import queue

from pprint import pprint


import asyncio

def start_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
    
    
def exception_handler(loop, context):
    print('Exception handler called')
    pprint(context)
       
async def startProcess(name):
    try:
        dfdf
        print(' Started-----------> ',name)
        
        while True:
            print("Sleeping...",name)
            time.sleep(5)
            
            
        return "Thread finish"     
        
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

async def main_app():
    
    loop1 = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop1.set_exception_handler(exception_handler)

    process1_Tread = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(loop1,))
    process1_Tread.start()   
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(startProcess("Thread1"), loop1)
    try:
        print("success:", fut.result())
    except:
        print("exception:", fut.exception())

   
    
   

    #consume signaling
    while True:
         print("Sleeping main thread...")
         time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main_app())

    finally:
             
        print("Exit...")
```